# Increment strings based on their counts in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe where I would like to increment strings based on their counts in Python

**Data**

```
id  type    date       count
aa  hi      q1 2023    2
aa  hey     q2 2023    3
bb  hi      q1 2023    2
```

**Desired**

```
id  count   type    date
aa  hi01    hi      q1 2023
aa  hi02    hi      q1 2023
aa  hey01   hey     q1 2023
aa  hey02   hey     q1 2023
aa  hey03   hey     q1 2023
bb  hi01    hi      q1 2023
bb  hi02    hi      q1 2023
```

**Doing**

*I believe I have to perform a 'melt' to expand the dataset*

```
(df.melt(id_vars=['id', 'type', 'date'], value_name='count') # reshape data
   .sort_values(by=['date', 'variable'])
```

*A SO user suggested this which works to increment*

```
count=lambda d: d['type']+d.groupby(['id', 'date', 'type']).cumcount().add(1).astype(str).str.zfill(2)
```

I am researching how to combine these, any suggestion is appreciated

Comment: We seem to be doing almost the same thing again. [Expand counted row value into separate rows, adding distinct ID in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67529618/15497888)

Comment: Scale up the DataFrame.`df = df.reindex(index=df.index.repeat(df['count'])).reset_index(drop=True)` Then the answer from the previous question works. `df['count'] = df['type']+df.groupby(['id', 'date', 'type']).cumcount().add(1).astype(str).str.zfill(2)`

Comment: @HenryEcker I went ahead and did this 
df['count'] = df['type']+df.groupby(['id', 'date', 'type']).cumcount().add(1).astype(str).str.zfill(2)
 but its just giving count 1 - I think this question is a bit different

Comment: Again you scaled up the DataFrame first? That's the core new component and the primary duplicate link. `df = df.reindex(index=df.index.repeat(df['count'])).reset_index(drop=True)` this happens _before_ enumerating groups.

Comment: ok thank you,  sorry about that @HenryEcker it works

Comment: No need to be sorry. Glad you got it worked out. The new issue is that your initial DataFrame is too small, so you just need to make it the correct size. Then the counting by groups will work as expected.